# Convert pcd files to pointcloud2

Tags: ros, lidar

i have many pcd files which were collected in every scan of a lidar. I want to convert my pcd files into pointcloud2 format to use them as a rosbag. I saw the pcd_to_pointcloud from point cloud library, however it is only applicable to a single pcd file. How is it possible to iterate this code for multiple pcd files?

`rosrun pcl_ros pcd_to_pointcloud <file.pcd> [ <interval> ]`

Files are like scan1.pcd scan2.pcd scan3.pcd etc.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You could do the loop in your shell. For example, the bash command would look as follows:

```
for F in my_pcd_directory/*.pcd; do rosrun pcl_ros pcd_to_pointcloud ${F} 0; done
```

This loop publishes all pcd files one by one.

Starting a `rosbag record --all` or `rosbag record cloud_pcd` in another shell records the published point clouds and stores them in a bag in your current working directory. Of course, you need to start the recording before running the for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

Some solution in Python

```
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

path = "/your/path/to/pcd_files/"

pcd_files = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]

for file in pcd_files:
    cmd = "rosrun pcl_ros pcd_to_pointcloud " + path+file
    os.system(cmd)
```